# What's the point to allow statements directly in the class body?

Tags: python

I was wondering what would be use cases for executing statements outside any methods:

```
class AClass:

    print('Your class object is being built...')

    def __init__(self, welcome):
        self.welcome = welcome
        print('Done! You can use it now!')

    def use_it(self, name):
        print(self.welcome, name + '!')

AClass('Welcome').use_it('World')
```

Comment: What's the point to disallow statements in the class body?

Comment: @wim: If you ask me, I don't know, tell me...

Comment: My argument is:  there is no reason to disallow it, so, that's why it's not disallowed.

Comment: @wim: That makes sense. I didn't know either though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything in a class definition is code. Each `def` is a statement that gets executed. It's not so much that there's a specific use for executing statements in a class definition, it's that class definitions aren't anything special in Python and just consist of a bunch of normal statements in a temporary namespace.

But as for actual use cases, you can do things like this:

```
class Foo:
    def bar(self):
        pass

    baz = bar  # alias
```

Or any other dynamic shenanigans you can think of.

Comment: Seems obvious now! Still any use further than assignment?

Comment: You can use loops, if you find any use for them…? You can use `if..else` to define different methods, e.g. based on the Python version…? I would (again) highlight the fact that you can execute *any* sort of code which defines the class structure in *any* dynamic way you need. There isn't a whole lot of need for it *typically*, but if you find yourself in some specific situation you're not restricted by language mechanics only allowing a special subset of expressions.